# Proof that if $a_n\to +\infty$ then $\frac{a_n}{e^{a_n}}\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My initial attempt is to use the ratio test, but I don't have any information about the following quantities
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \;\;\;\frac{e^{a_n}}{e^{a_{n+1}}}$$
My second attempt is to use the limit definition knowing that $a_n\to +\infty$ so
$$\forall\; M>0 \;\exists\;N\;\text{s.t.}\;\forall\; n>N\;\text{then}\;a_n>M$$
We know that $\forall\; n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a_n<e^{a_n}$ then $$e^{a_n}>a_n>M$$ i.e. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{a_n}=\infty$$ but I'm unable to come to any conclusion about $\frac{a_n}{e^{a_n}}$

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/430447/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/578133/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3186323/42969, also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3401790/42969

Comment: More generally: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2575379/42969

Comment: Hint:  $e^{a_n} > a_n^2/2$ when $a_n > 0$..

Comment: As you'll see from the links provided, the key is to replace $a_m$ by a real variable $x$ and use calculus (e.g. l'Hopital's rule, or Taylor approximations, or...).